# How can I get the editor font in Netbeans 7.4 to look like it did in 7.3?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

I'm on a mac with Retina display.  I have Netbeans 7.3 running on Java 1.6 (as required for Retina display) and Netbeans 7.4 running on Java 1.7_45 (as required for retina display).  The fonts in 7.4 don't as good (see screen shot).  I've tried playing with the settings and sizing etc to no avail. By the way, the scroll bar motion is choppy in Netbeans 7.4 as well.  [image: Screen shot comparison of Netbeans 7.3 (on the left) and 7.4 (on the right)]

Answer (score 1):

The default font on my Windows 7 box is "Monospaced 13" which looks closer to your NB 7.3 setting (although, obviously, not as sexy).

Tools/Options/Fonts & Colors/Syntax/Font

Comment: Both my NB 7.3 and NM 7.4 are configured to default "Monospaced 13" on my Mac ... but for some reason it doesn't look right on 7.4 (which has newer version of Java as a requirement ... which may be a hint?)

Comment: I think the answer may be here: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=229029

Comment: Changing to Courier did help.  Font still looks a little bit lighter weight or something, but improved for sure.